# Debugging cuda kernel code on Ubuntu Nsight?

Tags: debugging, cuda

I have a desktop with 2 cuda cards attached and I try to debug the cuda code by just putting some breakpoints into the lines of kernel. However debugger shows only the entrance and the end bracket of the kernel function. It does not give the ability of stepping on the kernel function body. It merely ignores. I have read that to debug an GPU kernel you need to run the code onto graphic card not used by the system currently. On this basis I also tried to run debugger by setting my active GPU to my second one (not used by the system) but still debugger ignores the kernel body. How could I solve that problem, having functioning CUDA debugger? Otherwise it is so painful to code complex cuda kernels.

Might be associated with current driver version that is 304 now on, at bumblebee optimus card?

Comment: Are you using cuda-gdb?  Or Nsight EE?  Are you compiling with the -G switch? Try putting a breakpoint at the entry to the kernel (i.e. issue the command `break mykernel` or whatever your kernel name is) and then see if, after hitting that breakpoint, you can then set breakpoints in the kernel code.  The cuda-gdb manual also has sample exercises you can try.

Comment: Using cuda-gdb as in the default settings of the Nsight. I also tried to debug it on terminal directly with cuda-gdb but still same problem.

Comment: I can't tell from your response if you tried my suggestion. Did you try setting a breakpoint at the kernel name, then run until that breakpoint is hit, and then set breakpoints within the kernel?  I would recommend doing this on the GPU that is not driving a display, and configure that GPU so that X is not using it (i.e. it does not show up in your `xorg.conf` file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is perfectly driver issue. I updated from 310.4 to 319.17 and everything is fine now.

Comment: I Have the same problem as you. My driver is 304.108 and cannot set a breakpoint in device code. Does it means that the kernel is not running on the gpu ? or is it noly a problem related to the CUDA debugger?

Answer (score 0):

This is most often caused by the kernel not being launched on the device. Make sure you check all error codes (and try adding cudaDeviceSynchronize after kernel call and check its error code as well). Common mistake is compiling kernel for wrong SM version. Also try printing out available CUDA devices from within your application.

Note that there's also a chance you have some setup issue - e.g. make sure Nouveau driver is properly blacklisted. In some cases X may use your device even if no display is connected - try explicitely setting the PCI ID in xorg.conf.

To specify adapter by PCI ID:

1. Obtain list of you device IDs by executing "lspci | grep NVI" from your shell. This is what I get on my system:

   > ```
   > 03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 103b (rev a1)
   > 03:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0e1a (rev a1)
   > 05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G98 [Quadro NVS 295] (rev a1)
   > ```
2. To use Quadro for display I add BusID to my /etc/X11/xorg.conf. This is what I have on my system:

   > ```
   > Section "Device"
   >     Identifier     "Device0"
   >     Driver         "nvidia"
   >     VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
   >     BoardName      "GeForce GTX 280"
   >     BusID          "PCI:5:0:0"
   >     #BusID          "PCI:3:0:0"
   > EndSection
   > ```

Note that strings Identifier and BoardName are merely UI labels - all I have to do to switch between devices with different SM versions is shutdown desktop (for Ubuntu GNOME - service lightdm stop), move comment, start the DM (service lightdm start).

Also make sure you have only one Device section in your xorg.conf

Comment: how can I do the second half of suggestions

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug errors that may occur when you launch a kernel you can define this:

```
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
__host__ inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
         if (abort) exit(code);
    }
}
```

and call your kernel like this:

```
kernel<<<...>>>(...);
gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
```

Basically you can wrap every cuda function calls with `gpuErrchk`.
Hope that helped a little.